# ESP8266 Switching firmware on the fly

Tags: esp8266, esp32

Can you help me out to understand if this is possible with ESP8266 / 32 ?

I have a main binary that i upload to the chip, let's call it **A** - that's done from arduino.

**A** starts to work, but communicates every couple of minutes with central server polling for a *task*.

If there is a task - let's call it **B**

**A** downloads it and stores it on SPIFFS.

Now what should happen is that **A** uploads it, reboots and **B** starts to work.

When **B** finishes it loads up again **A** and the circle closes - this process goes on forever.

Questions:

1) Is it possible that a stored on SPIFFS binary file can be uploaded to the chip? Like OTA does via www.

2) Can i somehow store **A** onto the SPIFFS, so that when **B** finishes i reupload **A** ?

Thanks for any input into this

Comment: why don't you have a single program that does both **A** and **B**?

Comment: Look at what ArduinoOTA does.

Comment: @Majenko - right, but i would then have to ask for firmware via WWW i don't speak to Web server, i download the binary from a dedicated grid computing system. 

So maybe you know if i can i download binary to SPIFFS and upload to chip other way than OTA?

Comment: @jsotola because **B** changes and is sent from a distributed system, has nothing to do with **A**. Binaries sent from distributed system will be different all the time.

Comment: Look at what ArduinoOTA does. I say again. Look at what it does. Don't use it. Just look at what it does.

Comment: @Majenko got your point now, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i've found an answer to my question here

https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=11324

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

#include "FS.h"



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  SPIFFS.begin();
  Dir dir = SPIFFS.openDir("/");

  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);

  File file = SPIFFS.open("/blinkESP.bin", "r");


  uint32_t maxSketchSpace = (ESP.getFreeSketchSpace() - 0x1000) & 0xFFFFF000;
  if (!Update.begin(maxSketchSpace, U_FLASH)) { //start with max available size
    Update.printError(Serial);
    Serial.println("ERROR");
  }

  while (file.available()) {
    uint8_t ibuffer[128];
    file.read((uint8_t *)ibuffer, 128);
    Serial.println((char *)ibuffer);
    Update.write(ibuffer, sizeof(ibuffer));

  }


  Serial.print(Update.end(true));
  digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);
  file.close();
}

void loop() {

}
```

Will give it a try and revert back to confirm if it answers my question.

Comment: Confirmed,works like a charm. Flashes firmware with a file from SPIFFS.

Answer (score 0):

The esp8266 Arduino package has 3 libraries for firmware update.

- ArduinoOTA for upload from Arduino IDE
- ESP8266HTTPUpdateServer for upload with web browser
- **ESP8266httpUpdate library to check a web server for new version of the
  firmware**